# DELETE FROM (SELECT ...) SAP HANA

Tags: subquery, delete-row, hana

How come this does not work and what is a workaround?

```sql
    DELETE FROM
    (SELECT
     PKID
    , a
    , b)
    Where a > 1
```

> `There is a Syntax Error at "(".`

`DELETE FROM (TABLE) where a > 1` gives the same syntax error.

I need to delete specific rows that are flagged using a rank function in my select statement.

Comment: The syntax error occurs because you have to specify the table name from which you want to Delete after the word FROM, on the second version of your Delete, remove the parenthesis around the table name, there is no need for them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now put a table immediately after the DELETE FROM and put WHERE restrictions on the DELETE and in a small series of self-joins of the table.

```
DELETE FROM TABLE1
WHERE x IN
    (SELECT A.x
    FROM (SELECT x, r1.y, r2.y, DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION by r1.y, r2.y ORDER by x) AS RANK
        FROM TABLE2 r0
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 r1 on r0.x = r1.x
        INNER JOIN TABLE1 r2 on r0.x = r2.x
        WHERE r1.y = foo and r2.y = bar
        ) AS A
    WHERE A.RANK > 1
    )
```